# Store last subscriptions of consumers in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, rx-java

I have Rx Stream where I'm using a grouped observable to have multiple observable according to a discriminant value. The thing is that I want to keep in memory the last subscription of each group observable in order to delete the stream when a new one is created (unsubscribe)

I'm using a simple Hashmap to store value according to a key which is an observable it self but it doesn't to worth it.

Here is where I am so far:

```
stream
.groupBy(ts -> ts.getLogin())
        .map(receptor -> receptor.asObservable())
        .forEach(consumer -> {
            controlConsumer(consumer);
        });

public void controlConsumer(Observable<Number> pConsumer) {

Subscription mySubscription = pConsumer
 .buffer(2,1)
 .subscribe();

    // Remove the current consumer last subscription if existing

    if(consumersLastSubcriptions.containsKey(pConsumer)) {
        LOG.info("removing last subscription");
        Subscription lLastSubscription = consumersLastSubcriptions.get(pConsumer);
        lLastSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    // store the new consumer subscription
    consumersLastSubcriptions.put(pConsumer, lSubscription);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Actually i might have different items defined by the login of the user emitting them. What i want is to store the last subscription of each user in order to remove it when i need to recreate a new one when needed. My purpose is to shutdown every stream no more used and don't let them open for nothing.

Comment: This looks weird to me. I'd appreciate a higher level description of what you want.

Comment: Actually i might have different items defined by the login of the user emitting them. What i want is to store the last subscription of each user in order to remove it when i need to recreate a new one when needed. My purpose is to shutdown every stream no more used and don't let them open for nothing

Comment: That's just a repeat of your question text. What's the higher level use case you're seeking to solve by storing subscriptions? I ask this because I doubt this is a good idea.

Comment: The use case is that for each time i'm controling consumer flow ( controlConsumer() method ) i'm creating a new stream. I keep those subscriptions stored in order to deleted them each time i create a new one. If i don't, every unsed stream will remain open. The only way to delete it is to keep it at creation

Comment: Thanks but by higher level I really mean can you describe what you want to do without referring to streams or subscriptions? Then we can figure out what is the best way to do what you want.

Comment: user is sending data to a second one. For checking the consumer flow, i'm calculating a delay between emission and reception. Well this calculation is made when every new user arrive specified by it's login( in the grouped observable). I want to shutdown the stream when the user leave and create a new one if this latter comes back. 

For this i'm sorting the current stream for each user in a hashMap. When restarting the calculation i want to be sure that every previous subscription are deleted. So i check if any previous subscription related to this user are in the hashmap